# Room with Android Query. This query working in another SQLite browser but not in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have written one simple query and is working fine, fast in the DB browser, but query not working in Android. I don't understand why. Another simple query, "Select * from table" is ok. Error/warning does not occur. Path: ForgroundService - > inner class myThread

my code:

```
override fun run() {
    val xListFromDB :List<xDataFromDBToServer> = 
      AppDatabase.getInstance(mContext).xValueDatabaseDao().getData();
    Log.e(TAG, "$TAGDBTHREAD + allxData  ${xListFromDB.size}")   //--> is 0
}
```

and DAO

```
@Query("SELECT 
         (CASE  
         when xDataValue.id IS NULL  
         THEN -1  
         ELSE xDataValue.id  
         END) AS uid,   
        'x' AS type,
         (CASE  
         when xData.sentAt IS NULL  
         THEN 0  
         ELSE xData.sentAt  
         END) AS sentAt,   
         xDataValue.Value AS value
         FROM xData   
         INNER JOIN xDataValue ON (xDataValue.xDataId =  xData.uid)   
        WHERE xData.uid IN (SELECT uid  
          FROM xData  
           WHERE sentAt IS NULL  
            AND uid IN (SELECT xDataId  
              FROM xDataValue)  
            ORDER BY uid ASC  
            LIMIT 20)")
fun getData(): List<xDataFromDBToServer>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks, guys

Comment: how exactly is it not working? What it does instead?

Comment: nothing :D no error no warning no runtimeException , Try catch- > nothing exception , so is result empty array.  But valid result is ~ 100 row

Comment: I'd suggest trying without the where clause e.g. @Query("SELECT (CASE when xDataValue.id IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE xDataValue.id END) AS uid, 'x' AS type, (CASE when xData.sentAt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE xData.sentAt END) AS sentAt, xDataValue.Value AS value FROM xData INNER JOIN xDataValue ON (xDataValue.xDataId = xData.uid) /*WHERE xData.uid IN (SELECT uid FROM xData WHERE sentAt IS NULL AND uid IN (SELECT xDataId FROM xDataValue) */ ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 20)"). If that produces results then progressively apply the WHERE clause (I suspect that asSent may never be null).

Comment: Yes i tried but this query is result 100 row in dbBorwser , and result [] in Android on the same database. therefore i dont understand.

Comment: So, i tried everithing , but nothing happend, .. it was a big bugbear because i delete database and restart app,, voala worked -_- .